# Getting the hostnames for IP addresses

Tags: unix

Is there any way that I can get only the Hostnames for each IP address?

When I use nslookup command or other commands i get a lot of information but I only want to get the hostname

Comment: Do you know the options for cut?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `host` like this:

```
$ host 192.168.1.1 | rev | cut -d ' ' -f1 | rev
OpenWrt.lan.
```